# Docker container failing to install mongo

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to install Mongo but it's failing.

Here is my Docker file:

```
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes mongodb-org=2.6.3 && \
    service mongod stop
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

VOLUME /data/db

RUN echo "mongodb-org hold" | dpkg --set-selections && \
echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | dpkg --set-selections && \
echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | dpkg --set-selections && \
echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | dpkg --set-selections && \
echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

Here is the error:

```
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
 mongodb-org
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks for any help.

-dj

Comment: You're missing the first half of your Dockerfile, so your problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Also, running the apt-get clean ... etc, as a separate RUN command won't reduce the size of your final image by a single byte. All of the files are still in a prior layer and need to be shipped with every push/pull, just concealed  by the rm in a later layer. You should merge that with the prior RUN command.